# Doubt about pushforwards

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions, pushforward

Given the smooth function $\psi:M\to N$, where $M$ and $N$ are two differentiable manifolds, we have introduced the pushforward map $\psi_{*,p}:T_pM\to T_{\psi(p)}N$ with $p\in M$ and the image of this map is defined as
$$\psi_{*,p}(v)(f)=v(f\circ\psi)\text{ where }v\in T_pM,f\in \mathcal C^{\infty}_{loc}(M).$$
Sometimes we only write $\psi_{*,p}(v)$, where $v$ is a derivation of the tangent space $T_pM$ ($v$ can also act on the germ of the smooth functions), and we compute the image of the derivation $v$ through $\psi_{*,p}$ without considering the action of the tangent vector on a generic smooth function. I'm not really understanding how to interpret this computation.
I'll try to do an example: Let's consider two differentiable manifolds $M$ and $N$ and their (local) charts $(V\subset M,\psi)$, $(W\subset N ,\varphi)$ such that $\psi:U\to\mathbb R^m$ and $\varphi:W\to \mathbb R^n$. Suppose that $M$ has coordinate functions $x^1,\dots,x^m$ and $N$ has coordinate functions $y^1,\dots,y^n$. Then let $f:M\to N$ be a smooth function.
If I now take the tangent vector $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\bigg|_{\psi^-1(q)}$, how can I write explicitily $f_{*}\bigg(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\bigg|_{\psi^-1(q)} \bigg)$ in terms of the coordinate functions?

Answer (score 2):

By definition, given a smooth function $g:M\to \mathbb{R}$, we have$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}(g)\Bigg|_{q}:=\frac{\partial g\circ \psi^{-1}}{\partial x^i}\Bigg|_{\psi(q)}$$
Thus (now $g$ is a smooth function on $N$, or it is defined locally around $f(p)$, depending on your definition of tangent space, but it does not make any difference since all of our computations are local)
$$\left(f_*\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right)\right)(g)=\frac{\partial (g\circ f\circ \psi^{-1})}{\partial x^i}=\frac{\partial (g\circ\varphi^{-1}\circ\varphi\circ f\circ \psi^{-1})}{\partial x^i}$$
Let us write $\hat f:=\varphi\circ f\circ \psi^{-1}$, i.e. the coordinate expression of $f$ and similarly $\hat g=g\circ \varphi^{-1}$. By the chain rule we get (writing ${\hat {f}}^j$ for the components of $\hat f$):
$$\frac{\partial \hat g\circ\hat f}{\partial x^i}=\sum_j \frac{\partial \hat g}{\partial x^j}\frac{\partial {\hat f}^j}{\partial x^i}=\sum_j \frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}(g) \partial_i{\hat f}^j$$
Thus, in coordinates, $f_*=J\hat f$, i.e. the jacobian of $\hat f$.

Comment: So, indipendently of the action  of the partial derivative on a smooth function, I can interpret $f_*(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^i})$ as an element in $T_{f(p)}N$.  Is it correct to define $$(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^i})_p:=\psi^{-1}_{*,\psi(p)}( (\dfrac{\partial}{\partial r^i})_{\psi(p)} )?$$

Comment: In your definition $g\circ \psi:M\to\mathbb R^m\to \mathbb R$ iff $M=\mathbb R^m$, while $g\circ\psi^{-1}:\mathbb R^m\to M\to \mathbb R$ and it seems more correct... Maybe I'm missing something

Comment: @Alchemist Yes sorry, it should indeed by $\psi^{-1}$, I will edit the answer. I am noot sure what you mean with $\psi^{-1}$ in your first comment (is it the map $M\to N$ or a chart?)

Comment: @Alchemist Is not that you can _interpret_ $f_*\left(\partial_i\right)$ as an element of $T_{f(p)}N$, it is _defined_ as an element of $T_{f(p)}N$

Comment: Okok. I've seen the edit buy maybe you forgot to evaluate the derivative in $\psi (q)$ in the first line.

Comment: @Alchemist Indeed, that was a typo, thanks. (Note that here $q$ is a point on the manifold, just to be clear)